# Elephant Bird Pig TypeRef ClassNotFoundException

Tags: apache-pig, protocol-buffers, elephantbird

I am trying to process data encoded in protocol-buffer to its pig representation using elephant-bird 4.1. Relevant Pig code:

```
REGISTER '/home/ubuntu/elephant-bird/core/target/elephant-bird-core-4.1-SNAPSHOT.jar';
REGISTER '/home/ubuntu/elephant-bird/pig/target/elephant-bird-pig-4.1-SNAPSHOT.jar';
REGISTER '/home/ubuntu/elephant-bird/hadoop-compat/target/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1-SNAPSHOT.jar';

REGISTER '/home/ubuntu/libraryContainingProto.jar';

DEFINE ProtobufBytesToTuple com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.piggybank.ProtobufBytesToTuple('com.my.converted.proto.class');

raw_protobuffer = LOAD 'hbase://table' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('cf:cl') AS (downloader:chararray);
parsed = FOREACH raw_protobuffer GENERATE ProtobufBytesToTuple($0);
```

Whenever I try to do the conversion, it fails miserably with the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.piggybank.ProtobufBytesToTuple' with arguments '[com.my.converted.proto.class]'
    at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.java:618)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.expression.UserFuncExpression.getFieldSchema(UserFuncExpression.java:193)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.FieldSchemaResetter.execute(SchemaResetter.java:264)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.expression.AllSameExpressionVisitor.visit(AllSameExpressionVisitor.java:143)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.expression.UserFuncExpression.accept(UserFuncExpression.java:88)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.ReverseDependencyOrderWalker.walk(ReverseDependencyOrderWalker.java:70)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:52)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.SchemaResetter.visitAll(SchemaResetter.java:67)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.SchemaResetter.visit(SchemaResetter.java:122)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOGenerate.accept(LOGenerate.java:246)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DependencyOrderWalker.walk(DependencyOrderWalker.java:75)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.SchemaResetter.visit(SchemaResetter.java:114)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOForEach.accept(LOForEach.java:76)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DependencyOrderWalker.walk(DependencyOrderWalker.java:75)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:52)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.expandAndResetVisitor(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:392)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildForeachOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:924)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.foreach_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:14195)
"~/pig_1379411496557.log" [readonly] 396L, 30186C                                                                 13,1-8        Top
    at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.java:618)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.expression.UserFuncExpression.getFieldSchema(UserFuncExpression.java:193)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.FieldSchemaResetter.execute(SchemaResetter.java:264)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.expression.AllSameExpressionVisitor.visit(AllSameExpressionVisitor.java:143)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.expression.UserFuncExpression.accept(UserFuncExpression.java:88)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.ReverseDependencyOrderWalker.walk(ReverseDependencyOrderWalker.java:70)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:52)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.SchemaResetter.visitAll(SchemaResetter.java:67)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.SchemaResetter.visit(SchemaResetter.java:122)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOGenerate.accept(LOGenerate.java:246)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DependencyOrderWalker.walk(DependencyOrderWalker.java:75)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.SchemaResetter.visit(SchemaResetter.java:114)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOForEach.accept(LOForEach.java:76)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DependencyOrderWalker.walk(DependencyOrderWalker.java:75)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:52)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.expandAndResetVisitor(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:392)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildForeachOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:924)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.foreach_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:14195)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1623)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:799)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:517)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:392)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:184)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.java:586)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twitter/elephantbird/util/TypeRef
    at com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.piggybank.ProtobufBytesToTuple.<init>(ProtobufBytesToTuple.java:37)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.twitter.elephantbird.util.TypeRef
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 43 more
```

I suspect this might have to do with including appropriate Jars, from what I see these dependency should be in elephant-bird-core.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce the same error, when I have excluded the 'elephant-bird-core' library.  So I am suspecting there is something wrong with jar.

You can check if the jar has the TypeRef.class by following command

```
jar -xvf elephant-bird-core-4.1-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep "TypeRef.class"
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The jar is fine, I went throught the same check you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it boiled down to the fact that simply using REGISTER from the grunt would not provide the libraries for the computation on the cluster.

In order to get them working I had to (in my case) drop elephant-bird-pig, elephant-bird-core and elephant-bird-hadoop-compat to the /usr/lib/hadoop directory.